# How can I download .aspx pages from SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, aspx, pages, download, archive

I want to archive some old pages from SharePoint Online but unfortunately there is no simple "Download-button" available like the one for the files. Is there a way to download and/or transfer without using PowerShell? If not, what is the best way to get it done via PowerShell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Classic SharePoint:**

I have mentioned two approaches to download/export files/pages/documents. It will support to both modern and classic SharePoint versions

**Approach 1:**

Update the below URL with your domain and page parameters

http://sharepoint.com/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://sharepoint.com/pages/test.aspx

**Approach 2:**

Using **SharePoint designer** we can export the pages/files. I have attached the screenshot below.

[image]

**Modern SharePoint:**

We have Command bar to download the files/documents/pages in the modern experience. I have attached the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: If above answer is satisfying your question then, please accept it so it will help the other people

Comment: The 1st option (manually typing the URL for "download.aspx?SourceUrl=..." worked great.  Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunatelly nor the first approach neither the second one works for me. There is no download button for anything in page folder. The link to the first url returns an error page.

Comment: In order do enable modern authentification for SharePoint Designer see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/sharepoint-designer-and-modern-authentication/ba-p/382774

Answer (score 1):

If you are using classic SharePoint sites, you will be open the site with SharePoint designer.

If you are using modern SharePoint sites, you can use VScode and SPGo extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SiteGo.spgo

Please note that you require to configure your Remote folders in JSON file to access SharePoint online contents.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=de2txBruxfA

Comment: SPGo Extension works great

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of them

- Site pages are stored in document libraries, you can download them by
  opening the library in which they are hosted.  For example in the
  default team site of SharePoint the home.aspx page is stored in a
  director called 'Site Pages' if you right click the page name in the 
  library you can 'save target as...' this can then be directed to any 
  location you would like.  It will save the page for you.
- You could also download SharePOint Designer and copy the page out of there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some customization on SharePoint pages, just use [SharePoint Designer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introducing-sharepoint-designer-66bf58fe-daeb-4fa6-ae84-fd600e0005c1). You can add custom css, JS, HTML code to it. What is your goal? Would you like to share us a bit more information for downloading .aspx pages?

Answer (score 0):

this really needs to be removed or updated.  you can't download pages from the Modern SharePoint Online Communications or Teams sites, using either SPGo in VS Code or SharePoint Designer.  They are both blocked by Microsoft now.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "style": {
    "border-radius": "5px",
    "margin": "5px 0px",
    "padding": "0px",
    "visibility": "=if([$File_x0020_Type] == '', 'hidden', 'visible')"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "txtContent": "Download",
      "style": {
        "text-decoration": "none",
        "padding": "10px 0px",
        "width": "100%"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "href": "= @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=' + [$UniqueId]",
        "target": "_blank",
        "class": "ms-fontColor-white"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Source https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/generic-download-file-button

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint online modern experience, you can use JSON column formatting to download the individual pages.

You can use JSON like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "button",
    "style": {
        "border-radius": "5px",
        "margin": "5px 0px",
        "padding": "0px",
        "visibility": "=if([$ContentType] == 'Folder', 'hidden', 'visible')"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-themePrimary"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "txtContent": "Download",
            "style": {
                "text-decoration": "none",
                "padding": "10px 0px",
                "width": "100%"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "href": "= @currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=' + [$UniqueId]",
                "target": "_blank",
                "class": "ms-fontColor-white"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Source**: [SharePoint Online: Download files using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/11/10/sharepoint-online-download-files-using-json-formatting/)

**Example output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [SharePoint column-formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

- Open Google Chrome Developer Tools (F12)
- Go to Sources => Page
- Right click on File and choose "Save as..."

[image]