# How can I download .aspx page(s) from SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, aspx, pages, download

I want to archive some old pages from SharePoint Online but unfortunately there is no simple "Download-button" available like the one for the files. Is there a way to download and/or transfer without using PowerShell? If not, what is the best way to get it done via PowerShell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please refer this below article https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273056/how-can-i-download-aspx-pages-from-sharepoint-online/273137#273137

Answer (score 1):

**Classic SharePoint:**

I have mentioned two approaches to download/export files/pages/documents. It will support to both modern and classic SharePoint versions

**Approach 1:**

Update the below URL with your domain and page parameters

http://sharepoint.com/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=http://sharepoint.com/pages/test.aspx

**Approach 2:**

Using **SharePoint designer** we can export the pages/files. I have attached the screenshot below.

[image]

**Modern SharePoint:**

We have Command bar to download the files/documents/pages in the modern experience. I have attached the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: If above answer is satisfying your question then, please accept it so it will help the other people.

Comment: Hi Karthikeyan, Unfortunately the download button is not showing and the URL leads to the "access denied" page. I suspect downloading the .aspx has been enabled. Is this possible? I will try SharePoint Designer to export the files.

Comment: May I know ur permission in that library and that particular item permission too @SHRS

Comment: I don't see 'Download' button when selecting 'Home' page of a Microsoft Teams associated SharePoint site - I am an 'Owner'.

Comment: Please ensure you selected any files then only it will be showing the download button

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to download pages. Just replace the below url with page url you want and your site url

```
http://<site URL>/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=/sites/sitename/library/folder/fileName.aspx
```

Comment: Hi Harshal, the URL leads to the "access denied" page. I suspect downloading the .aspx has been enabled. Is this possible?

Comment: <site URL> should be the url of the site which consists the page you want to download.